# .NET Charting Control, max value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, charts

I pretty much have everything setup by default, and it works for smaller numbers (9.22337 × 109), but when I try to add bigger numbers (9.9E+37) to the series, the control crashes. Upon further inspection into the stack trace, it seems to be a double-> decimal conversion error?

I guess I just want to know if this is a limitation of the control, or if maybe it requires some other configuration. Just from looking at what's happening, I'm guessing its a limitation, but I figured I'd ask here before giving up and trying to figure out a different way.

```
System.OverflowException occurred
   HResult=-2146233066
   Message=Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
       at System.Decimal..ctor(Double value)
       at System.Decimal.op_Explicit(Double value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.RoundedValues(Double inter, Boolean shouldStartFromZero, Boolean autoMax, Boolean autoMin, Double& min, Double& max)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateNumberAxis(Double& minimumValue, Double& maximumValue, Boolean shouldStartFromZero, Int32 preferredNumberOfIntervals, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis(Double& minimumValue, Double& maximumValue, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics       graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
  InnerException:
```

And heres the "disassembled" System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.RoundedValues function I picked out from dotPeek.

```
internal double RoundedValues(double inter, bool shouldStartFromZero, bool autoMax, bool autoMin, ref double min, ref double max)
    {
      if (this.axisType == AxisName.X || this.axisType == AxisName.X2)
      {
        if (this.margin == 0.0 && !this.roundedXValues)
          return inter;
      }
      else if (this.margin == 0.0)
        return inter;
      if (autoMin)
        min = min < 0.0 || !shouldStartFromZero && !this.ChartArea.stacked ? (double) (Decimal.op_Decrement((Decimal) Math.Ceiling(min / inter)) * (Decimal) inter) : 0.0;
      if (autoMax)
        max = max > 0.0 || !shouldStartFromZero ? (double) (Decimal.op_Increment((Decimal) Math.Floor(max / inter)) * (Decimal) inter) : 0.0;
      return inter;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to convert a very large value to decimal which is not enough to be fit in `decimal`. This is max supported vale for decimal `79228162514264337593543950335m` taken from `decimal.MaxValue` constant

Comment: Hello Hans, it's a line chart graphing measurements from an oscilloscope over time. One of the electrical engineers confirmed that it's a correct value.

Comment: 'Correct' by no mean that you can store it in any number type! Scale the data down before feeding them into the chart!

Comment: has there been any update on this? I'm having the same problem, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359790/net-charting-throws-decimal-overflow-exception